# Apple Script + Shell Script: How do I convert this shell script to apple script?

Tags: shell, applescript

```
cd ~/Library/Application\ Support/minecraft/;

if [ -d 'rezcraft_bin' ]
    then
        echo "backing up sanguine, switching to rezcraft"
        mv 'bin' 'sanguine_bin';
        mv 'rezcraft_bin' 'bin';
    else
        echo "backing up rezcraft, switching to sanguine"
        mv 'bin' 'rezcraft_bin';
        mv 'sanguine_bin' 'bin';        
fi
exit
```

like, I maybe a tutorial will help, idk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple: `do shell script "echo Hello World"`